# Как получить текст от EditText если я создаю его программно?

Tags: java, android

Я создаю N штук `EditText` программно:

```
 plain_text = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
 plain_text.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
 (
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
 ));
 plain_text.setId(textId);
 layout_row.addView(plain_text);
 textId++;
```

затем я хочу по очереди получить введенный текст с каждого добавленного `EditText`, но как мне получить текст с конкретного `EditText`?
 ведь `plain_text.getText.toString` не принимает в расчет id элемента?

Comment: А что вы вообще хотите сделать? Может этот подход неправильный

Comment: скорее всего вам нужен recyclerView + адаптер + ViewHolder

Comment: мне нужно небольшое количество полей ввода текста, предположительно до 10, более ничего в активности не будет поэтому я выбрал самый простой способ реализации с добавлением доп. полей по мере необходимости

Comment: @Howling ну я бы тогда нужное количество через верстку в layout сделал

Comment: @pavel163 я бы так и сделал, но нужное количество строк для ввода неизвестно заранее, поэтому изначально их нет вовсе, добавляю 1, если надо еще 1, и тд

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так можно сделать, но такой подход не очень хорош, как заметили в комментариях лучше использовать связку **recyclerView + адаптер + ViewHolder**.

Но если ты хочешь попробовать, то решение здесь простое использовать **tag** для **view**.

Например:

```
plain_text = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
 plain_text.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
 (
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
 ));
 plain_text.setTag(textId);
 layout_row.addView(plain_text);
 textId++;
```

**plain_text.setTag(textId)** присвоит **tag** твоему **view**.

Для того, чтобы получить результат от определенной view, тебе необходимо обратиться так:

```
layout_row.findViewWithTag(textId).getText()
```

где **layout_row.findViewWithTag(textId)** вернет твое **view** по **tag**.